# Use async with NodeJs MySQL driver

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I want to reform the function `router.get('/', etc)` to one that uses *async* and *await*. The `res.send` and `connection.query` are making the trouble I don't know how to handle them using async/await constructs.

I tried to use this function:

```
const awaitHandlerFactory = (middleware) => {
    return async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            await middleware(req, res, next)
        } catch (err) {
            next(err)
        }
    }
};
```

This is the code that i have in the file:

```
var express = require('express');
// const data = require("../data/repo");
var router = express.Router();

let mysql = require("mysql");
let config = require('../config/config.json');

let connection = mysql.createConnection(config);
connection.connect();
//
let guests = {};
let query1 = "select * from guests";
//GET home page.
 router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
     connection.query(query1,  function (err, rows) {
         guests['guests'] = rows;
         res.send(guests)
     });
 });
```

this function works the `router.get('/', etc...)`

I get this: and this is what i want.

```
 "guests": [
        {
            "event_id": 1,
            "guest_id": 1,
            "firstName": "lkasjdl;skj",
            "lastName": "lskajdfal;skdj",
            "role": "lsakdjfalskdjflks;adjf",
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
        },
```

Comment: What do you get? We can not see the actual output. Where awaitHandlerFactory is used?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the callback-style connection.query to something that can be awaited. `promisify` from `util` will do just that.

```
const express = require('express');
// const data = require("../data/repo");
const router = express.Router();

const util = require("util");
const mysql = require("mysql");
const config = require('../config/config.json');

const connection = mysql.createConnection(config);
const query = util.promisify(connection.query.bind(connection));
connection.connect();

const guests = {};
const query1 = "select * from guests";
//GET home page.
 router.get('/', async function(req, res, next) {
    try {
        const rows = await query(query1);
    } catch(ex) {
      //process your error
    }
    guests['guests'] = rows;
    res.send(guests);
 });
```

Comment: This way its best to use promise implementation of mysql2

Comment: @ngob I'm not familiar with mysql2, but you're free to edit the answer.

Comment: @ChiralMichael Thank you for your answer. But i get this error when i try it on postman. -> node:22268) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'typeCast' of undefined  -> Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2) ->  But if i use async and await i shouldnt use .catch() because it will do it for me. am i right?

Comment: @iloqleo No, you still need to catch exceptions (if you can process them). When using async/await you just try/catch like you would for synchronous code. I've edited my response to include this. You should process the error, if you can. In this case, there's not much for you to process. Usually, I'd just let the exception go and return the default 500 error. At any rate, take a look at your callstack to see where the error is coming from and fix that. I'm guess you aren't using connection.query correctly.

Comment: @iloqleo I have the same issue. I'm doing it exactly as ChiralMichael shows, so...

Comment: @Ngob is right, if mysql2 has a promise implementation, use that. I realized that you probably need to bind connection.query to get this to work like so: connection.query.bind(connection) . All the same, use the promise implementation of mysql2 if you can, it'll handle these details for you.